# Google Analytics no longer tracking all form submissions

Tags: wordpress, forms, google-analytics, gravity-forms-plugin

We have recently noticed that Google Analytics is no longer reporting all website form completions on 2 of our client’s websites.

Whenever a form is submitted, the website visitor is sent to a *'thank you'* page. This visit to the 'thank you page' is then automatically recorded as a form completion 'goal' in Google Analytics. Based on database extracts, we have determined however that almost 2/3 of all form completions are no longer reported in Google Analytics since around mid-January. All website forms are affected by the drop in reported goal completions.

This problem is only affecting two of our client websites, yet all of our websites use WordPress (latest version) as their CMS and the Gravity Forms plugin, which is a reputable, paid plugin. We have made no changes in Google Analytics or Gravity Forms.

Does anyone have any ideas what could possibly be the cause of this problem?

***Update: 20/03/2014**

Starting today Analytics has actually started showing more goals completions than the amount of forms being submitted... I am so confused by this problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user press submit button two to three times because of low internet speed, records save in database for every click to submit but your goal is set to thankyou page for completion. When after pressing submit two to three times, URL refresh to thankyou page only once and in analytics it sets one record. You have to write a script for submit button to break the query after user press it one time to get the authentic results. This is a normal issue.

Comment: We are aware of this issue, we've discounted the duplicates when counting the amount of entries but even so there is still a big difference. So something else is causing the error.

Comment: Starting today Analytics has actually started showing more goals completions than the amount of forms being submitted... I am so confused by this problem.

Comment: I shared this issue with my team and found that there are some issues in goal completions with analytics also. You should trust your database for best results.